# Is there a way to make a component that's only setting context not rerender on context update? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've got context and then a component that sets that context but then rerenders calling all the stuff that's in there unnecessarily.

Here's the code:

```
export const SelectedContentContext = createContext();
export const SelectedContentProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [selectedContent, setSelectedContent] = useState(0);

  return (
    <SelectedContentContext.Provider
      value={{ selectedContent, setSelectedContent }}
    >
      {children}
    </SelectedContentContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useSelectedContentValue = () => useContext(SelectedContentContext);
```

Then I import it in a component where I want to set it like this:

```
import { useSelectedContentValue } from "../context";
...
const { setSelectedContent } = useSelectedContentValue();
```

And set it like this:

```
setSelectedContent(c => c - 1)
```

But there is also a bunch of code including EventListeners that doesn't have to rerun but still reruns since the component uses Context.

So what I'm asking is if there's a way to somehow make it so it does not rerender. Like somehow making it into a separate component or custom hook or does the setState() from Context make it conjoined and there's no way around it.

---

Edit: better representation of how it actually looks.

```
export const Component = () => {
    const [node, setNode] = useState();

    return (
    <>
      <section ref={ref => setNode(ref)}><section/>
      {node ? <Component2 prop={node}/> : null}
    </>
    );
}
```

The component in which I setSelectedContent();.

```
import { useSelectedContentValue } from "../context";

export const Component2 = (props) => {
    let ref = props.prop;

    const { setSelectedContent } = useSelectedValue();

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        const handleEnd = (e) => {
          ...
          if(...){
              setSelectedContent(c => c + 1);
          }
        }

    ref.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd);

    return () => {
      ref.removeEventListener("touchend", handleEnd);
    };

    },[ref, setSelectedContent]);

    return null;
}
```

useEffect with return cleanup since I know setSelectedContent will cause a rerender and I will have to removeEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
export const Component = () => {
    const node = useRef();

    return (
    <>
      <section ref={node}><section/>
      {node ? <Component2 node={node}/> : null}
    </>
    );
}
```

then

```
import { useSelectedContentValue } from "../context";

export const Component2 = ({ node }) => {
    const { setSelectedContent } = useSelectedValue();

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        const handleEnd = (e) => {
          ...
          if(...){
              setSelectedContent(c => c + 1);
          }
        }

    node.current.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd);

    return () => {
      node.current.removeEventListener("touchend", handleEnd);
    };

    },[]);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I did a poor job at depicting the complexity of my code. I thought that would be the solution but since I want to setSelectedContent() in an "if" statement in an eventHandler I can't just put a Component there cuz it's just an expression and if I create a state and return that new Component based on that state the whole thing will rerender again.

Comment: updated code, now when you call setSelectedContent, the effect will not recreate the events

Comment: Oh, yeah I really need some sleep. I forgot that when it prints this after removing the dependencies: _"React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'ref' and 'setSelectedContent'. Either include them or remove the dependency array"_, it doesn't mean it wont work. Thanks Ben.